# Injecting Collection of Classes with Guice

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to inject things with Google Guice 2.0 and I have the following structure:

```
FooAction implements Action
BarAction implements Action
```

I then have an ActionLibrary with the following constructor:

```
ActionLibrary (List<Action> theActions)
```

When I request an instance of ActionLibrary from Guice, I would like Guice to identify both of the registered Action classes (FooAction, BarAction) and pass them into the constructor. The motivation here being that when I add a third action BazAction, it would be as simple as registering it in the Module and it would automatically be added to the list in the constructor.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you want for this is [Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings). Specifically, you want to bind a `Set<Action>` (not a `List`, but a `Set` is probably what you really want anyway) like this:

```
Multibinder<Action> actionBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Action.class);
actionBinder.addBinding().to(FooAction.class);
actionBinder.addBinding().to(BarAction.class);
```

Then you can `@Inject` the `Set<Action>` anywhere.

Comment: What about if `List` is actually required - and why not even `Collection<? extends Action>`?

Comment: `List` doesn't make sense because the whole idea of `Multibinder` is that it collects bindings from multiple modules... and there isn't a reliable user-defined order for the items. If you really need a `List` with items in a specific order, it only really makes sense to create that list yourself and bind it directly. But the typical use-case for `Multibinder` is binding multiple implementations of an interface, in which case order typically shouldn't matter and you don't want more than one of the same thing.

Answer (score 25):

Let me show you what I consider an even better way of multibinding things. If you want `Action`s to be pluggable and let anyone add them, it's often useful to provide a simple `Module` for someone to use that hides needing to instantiate the `Multibinder`. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class ActionModule extends AbstractModule {
  private Multibinder<Action> actionBinder;

  @Override protected void configure() {
    actionBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Action.class);
    configureActions();
  }

  /**
   * Override this method to call {@link #bindAction}.
   */
  protected abstract void configureActions();

  protected final LinkedBindingBuilder<Action> bindAction() {
    return actionBinder.addBinding();
  }
}
```

Now why is this better? It allows someone to use an `ActionModule` from anywhere to add more `Action`s via the standard binding API. I think it's more readable. Here's an example usage:

```
public final class MyStandardActionModule extends ActionModule() {
  @Override protected void configureActions() {
    bindAction().to(FooAction.class);
    bindAction().to(BarAction.class);
    // If you need to instantiate an action through a Provider, do this.
    bindAction().toProvider(BazActionProvider.class);
    // You can also scope stuff:
    bindAction().to(MySingletonAction.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

This pattern of using a `Module` to hide the multibinder is used in Guice code. It's a little work up front, but keeps things clean. You can also do something similar for a `MapBinder` if you need to. Keep in mind you can instantiate as many `ActionModule`s as you want.

Comment: Let me know if you have anymore questions about this approach :-)... it's pretty handy for writing libraries for configuring stuff.

Comment: Very clean and simple approach! +1