# How to inject a collection with provider

Tags: java, guice

My application has a class called Gateway and a json file with a set of these gateways. I already parsed this json, giving me a Set object. Now I want to create a Multibinder to inject this set throughout my code. So far, I've created this provider:

```
public class GatewaysProvider implements Provider<Set<Gateway>> {

@Override
public Set<Gateway> get() {
    try {
        File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/gateways.json").toURI());
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Set<Gateway>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader(file), listType);
    } catch (URISyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new HashSet<>();

}
```

}

What more should I do to be able to inject this set anywhere in my code, like this:

```
Set<Gateways> gateways;

@Inject
public AppRunner(Set<Gateway> gateways) {
    this.gateways = gateways;
}
```

Comment: How you want to inject this? Can you give an example from how it should look like for consume class?

Comment: I edited and added the constructor I want to inject the set

Comment: Are you using Spring or JavaEE? It seems that JavaEE, I'm just clarifying

Comment: Nope, that's a JavaSE with Swing components

Comment: look this aswere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410712/injecting-collection-of-classes-with-guice

Comment: BTW, `@Provider` and `@Inject` are actually parts of JavaEE platform

Comment: Guess I forgot to mention I'm using Guice as a DI mechanism

Comment: I should've guessed assuming you using `Gson`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the implementation of **dependency injection** mechanism.

You can do it yourself, but I'd suggest you to use existent DI library, like [EasyDI](https://github.com/lestard/EasyDI)

Please proceed, with steps below:

1. Add *EasyDI* to your classpath. With *Maven* it would be:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>eu.lestard</groupId>
       <artifactId>easy-di</artifactId>
       <version>0.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add wrapper type for your *Gateway* set, and adjust *Provider* correspondingly:

   ```
   public class GatewayContainer {
     Set<Gateway> gateways;

     public void setGateways(Set<Gateway> gateways) {
       this.gateways = gateways;
     }
   }

   public class GatewayProvider implements Provider<GatewayContainer> {

     @Override
     public GatewayContainer get() {
         try {
             File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/gateways.json").toURI());
             Type listType = new TypeToken<Set<Gateway>>() {
             }.getType();
             Set<Gateway> set = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader(file), listType);
             GatewayContainer container = new GatewayContainer();
             container.setGateways(set);
             return container;
         } catch (URISyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return new GatewayContainer();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Configure and use your context:

   ```
   public class AppRunner {
     GatewayContainer container;

     public AppRunner(GatewayContainer container) {
         this.container = container;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         EasyDI context = new EasyDI();
         context.bindProvider(GatewayContainer.class, new GatewayProvider());
         final AppRunner runner = context.getInstance(AppRunner.class);
     }
   }
   ```

Afterwards, you will get the *AppRunner* with all the injected dependencies.

**Note:** There is no usage of any sort of `@Inject`(or similar) annotation, because EasyDI not requires it by default

Comment: I've solved a bit differently, using Guice's TypeLiteral to bind the provider. Thank you anyway